# apache pig using mapreduce java getting exception

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am using pig-0.15 and hadoop 2.6. While connecting to HDFS using apache pig through `mapreduce`, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: **Failed to create DataStorage**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecException, IOException {

    PigContext s=new PigContext();

    PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("mapreduce");
    System.out.println(pigServer);
    pigServer.registerQuery("A = load 'hdfs://localhost:9000/pigdata/a.txt' using PigStorage(',')");
    pigServer.registerQuery("B = foreach A generate $0;");
    pigServer.store("B", "hdfs:/pigdata/ip.txt");

}
```

I have used pig-0.15 jar, hadoop-common:2.6.0, adoop-yarn-common:2.6.0, hadoop-core:1.2.0.

`INFO executionengine.HExecutionEngine: Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:9000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create DataStorage
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.init(HDataStorage.java:75)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.datastorage.HDataStorage.<init>(HDataStorage.java:58)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:241)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.init(HExecutionEngine.java:111)
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.connect(PigContext.java:311)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:226)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:214)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:206)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.<init>(PigServer.java:202)`

Comment: can you paste complete stacktrace?

Comment: `hdfs://localhost:9000:/pigdata/a.txt` looks suspicious to me. Usually default port is 8020 and then there's a `:` too much after the port. Try changing that to `hdfs://localhost:8020/pigdata/a.txt`

Comment: Thanks for reply .I was working with in console.But using java It thowing this exception.I checked with that what u sent.But  still It is showing same exception.